# Database structure for sport venue booking

Tags: django, database-design

I'm building a system in Django that allows booking of slots to play games at any sport venue.

Now, different sporting venues have different schedules. So I've thought of a plan that allows multiple venues to have a custom schedule built.

On the front end, I've managed to do this by setting up a simple form that takes in the slots, rates per slot, etc.

However, I'm not able to figure out a database structure where venues can have different schedule types.

For example, if you take a website such as http://bookmyshow.com/ and say search for a movie and then a cinema hall, different halls show different seating arrangements depending on the structure in the database. Sample screenshot

[image: For example]

How do I replicate such a system? I'm just not able to figure this one out.

Comment: The 2 examples seem fairly different. Start by recording the data you want to store and then look at normalizing it. Building the UI first is nice from a user perspective but not that useful in figuring out how it will work. It depends how you want to constrain things. You could just have an open/close time and allow any type booking for a location or you could just offer hour slots remember YAGNI and don't overcomplicate

Comment: @kayakpim, that helped a lot! I was able to come up with a solution that was much much simpler than what I thought originally. Thanks! :)